# image responsive issues with iphone

Tags: css, image, media-queries, media, responsive

I’ve been able to get my images to be mobile responsive and to resize correctly except for iPhones. These are images that are loaded as background images through css.  I am using media queries.

```
#wineClub{
        background:black url('/Winery/img/winebottles3.jpg') center center no-repeat fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
}

 /*For devices 400px and larger: */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 700px) {
    #wineClub { 
        background-image: url('/Winery/img/winebottles2.jpg')center center no-repeat fixed; 
         -webkit-background-size: cover;
         -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

What gives?

Comment: We want to help, but you've got to better describe the problem! Post a screenshot or detail how it looks now, and how you want it to look.

Comment: So the images in question look great on desktops, laptops, and all phones except the iPhone. The images are way way too big and you can't tell what they are because they are too large. They are set to : cover and height: 100%. I'm not sure why they are so big and only on iPhones.

Comment: I found an article by  Ryan Reese that says iPhones basically double the anticipated width of a device. I am using the meta tag as instructed, but it is still only displaying a portion of my image on my iPhone. So it is an extremely blown up image where I only see a fraction of it. My media queries are working on all other devices.